# Generate Loop looks infinite

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

I've got a script that will generate a map but as it is now, the browser thinks it is running an infinite loop. I know that it will run for possibly quite a long time but it shouldn't affect the browser.

Is there a way to tell the browser to continue the function regardless? Whenever I run it in the browser console I always get "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded".

My function:

```
function generateMap() {
    map = [];
    for (i1 = 0; i1 < size; i1++) {
        s = '';
        for (i2 = 0; i2 < size; i2++) {
            var r = getRandomInt(1,oneIn);
            if (r == oneIn) s += '1';
            else s += '0';
        }
        map.push(s);
    }
    if (!mapValid(map)) {
        generateMap();
    } else {
        writeToPage(map, 'map');
    }
}
```

The `mapValid()` function is rather big so I won't post it here but the entire script including the `mapValid()` function can be found http://jsfiddle.net/GrV8r/

Comment: Declare your variables with `var`, they're leaking.

Comment: I'm guessing `mapValid()` never returns false

Comment: Are you sure it's not infinite? If you change this to use a `while()` loop instead of a recursive function your browser will just freeze and never stop.

Comment: what is your defination for `size' inside the loop

Comment: @elclanrs The variables are declared. Just not in the snippet I posted.

Comment: @adeneo I think you mean true and it does on smaller sizes though I need larger sizes.

Comment: Why would you declare loop variables outside of the function scope?

Comment: @jhyap It's currently 15.

Comment: @elclanrs If you mean `i1` and `i2`, they don't need to be declared beforehand. You can just use `for(i = 0` if you really wanted.

Comment: No, you **do** have to declare them, really.

Comment: @Spedwards - well, yes, never returns true. The fact that the call stack is filled up is signs of a never ending function recursion, and it usually takes millions of function calls to do that, which indicates that you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaron recommended breaking, which is one option.

Another option is to use `setTimeout` to generate a map, then if that fails, generate another.

Using the `setTimeout` you can make sure it doesn't block the browser.

```
function generateMap() {
    map = [];
    for (i1 = 0; i1 < size; i1++) {
        s = '';
        for (i2 = 0; i2 < size; i2++) {
            var r = getRandomInt(1,oneIn);
            if (r == oneIn) s += '1';
            else s += '0';
        }
        map.push(s);
    }
    if (!mapValid(map)) {
        console.log("Generating another map.");
        // Note: There is no () after generateMap.  We are passing the function reference.
        window.setTimeout(generateMap, 25);

    } else {
        writeToPage(map, 'map');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `mapValid(map)` doesn't return `true` for thousands of maps.

That means the recursive approach doesn't work here. Use a loop instead:

```
while(true) {
   ... generate map ...
   if(mapValid(map)) break;
}
```

This approach won't exhaust the stack. For safety reasons, you should abort the loop, though so it doesn't block the browser for too long:

```
for(var guard=0; guard<10000; guard++) {
   ... generate map ...
   if(mapValid(map)) {
       writeToPage(map, 'map');
       return;
   }
}

...unable to generate a valid map...
```